# Select a subset of lists from list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list of lists of the following form:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.4
[[2]]
[1] 0.3
[[3]]
[1] 9
[[4]]
[1] 10
[[5]]
[1] 0.4

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.4
[[2]]
[1] 0.4
[[3]]
[1] 99
[[4]]
[1] 4
[[5]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0.3
[[2]]
[1] 0.3
[[3]]
[1] 2
[[4]]
[1] 08
[[5]]

...

[[100]]
[[100]][[1]]
[1] 0.4
[[2]]
[1] 0.1
[[3]]
[1] 0
[[4]]
[1] 7
[[5]]
```

I would like to select all lists that have 0.4 in their `[[i]][[1]]`.

That is, select

```
[[i]][[1]]==0.4
```

The results would be:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]
[1] 0.4
[[2]]
[1] 0.3
[[3]]
[1] 9
[[4]]
[1] 10
[[5]]
[1] 0.4

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.4
[[2]]
[1] 0.4
[[3]]
[1] 99
[[4]]
[1] 4
[[5]]
[1] 3
...
[[100]]
[[100]][[1]]
[1] 0.4
[[2]]
[1] 0.1
[[3]]
[1] 0
[[4]]
[1] 7
[[5]]
```

Can this be done without a `for` loop or something?

I tried selecting `[[i]][[1]]==0.4`, but it only returns truth conditions. What if I want to select based on multiple conditions? For example, `[[i]][[1]]==0.4 & [[i]][[2]]==0.9`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
ll[which(sapply(ll, `[[`, 1) == .4)]
```

But you might run into floating point problems....

---

Here's an MRE:

A `list` with 4 items.

```
ll <- list(list(.4, 1), list(.1, 2), list(.3, 3), list(.4, 4))
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 0.4
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 0.1
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1] 0.3
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
# [1] 3
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# [[4]][[1]]
# [1] 0.4
# 
# [[4]][[2]]
# [1] 4
```

Apply the proposed solution:

```
ll[which(sapply(ll, `[[`, 1) == .4)]
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 0.4
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 0.4
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 4
```

---

Adding multiple conditions is pretty similar:

```
ll[which(sapply(ll, `[[`, 1) == .4 & sapply(ll, `[[`, 2) == 1)]
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 0.4
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 1
```

Comment: great this works, how do I modify the code if I want multiple conditions to be fulfulled?

Comment: I have a list in a list, in a list in a list. Subsetting the first list based on the content of the last one works the same way as described here? I can't find any good example.